# replacing pixels in an imagewith pixels from another image python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to replace pixels less than value 50 in one image (src1) with pixels from another image (src2).
The code i am trying is as below.
The problem is it is taking lot of time. Can anyone guide me in using optimized way to do this

```
src1 = cv2.imread('')
src2 = cv2.imread('')
rows, cols, ch = src1.shape
result = src1.copy()    
for i in (xrange(rows)):
     for j in (xrange(cols)):
          k = src1[i,j]
          if (k.all() < 50):
              result[i,j] = src2[i,j]
              cv2.imwrite('',result)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, would mind update your post with more information, see [mcve].

Comment: please provide your entire code, as there are parts missing

Comment: @YakovDan  i have added every lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy for this.

```
src1 = cv2.imread('')
src2 = cv2.imread('')
r,c = np.where(src1<50)
src1[(r,c)] = src2[(r,c)]
```